# Pourquoi « DÉplantage » mais pas « REplantage » ?

Tags: préfixes, dictionnaires

Les mots « déplantation » et « replantation » figurent dans le Larousse (cf. http://www.larousse.fr/). Cependant, seul « déplantage » est listé (comme synonyme de « déplantation »).

**Question :** Pourquoi n'y retrouve-t-on pas aussi « replantage » ? Quel est le critère de sélection qui s'applique dans ce cas particulier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je doute qu'il y ait beaucoup de dictionnaires qui soient entièrement complets, surtout quand il s'agit de mentionner des dérivés. Bien que je ne sois pas du tout de la partie je peux imaginer que les choix des lexicographes sont variés et peuvent aller de la ligne éditoriale (public cible par exemple) aux raisons économiques (place limitée par exemple).

Le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/replantation) donne *replantation*, et *replantement*, mais pas *replantage*.

Wikipedia donne [*replantage*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/replantage), [*replantation*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/replantation) et [*replantement*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/replantement).

Mon édition du *Petit Robert* (1994) ne donne que *replantation*.
Mais le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* <sup>1</sup> donne  *replantation* (1791), *replantement* (1600) et *replantage* (1875), et signale que *replantation* s'est imposé devant les deux autres.
Donc confrontés aux choix éditoriaux, il est vraisemblable que les dictionnaires qui n'en mentionnent qu'un aient choisi de prendre le plus usité, à savoir *replantation*.

La popularité de replantation est d'ailleurs confirmée par le [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=replantation%2Creplantement%2Creplantage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3) suivant.

[image: replantation-replantage-replantement]

<sup>1. sld Alain Rey, Éditons Le Robert</sup>

Comment: Très intéressant... Merci de m'avoir fait découvrir la possibilité de créer de tels graphes !