# Web service or program that shows the use over time for a French word

Tags: vocabulaire, histoire, ressources

In English when I want to see the evolution of the use of a term over time, I can use Google as shown below. Is there any similar website or program for French?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any other website than google... Do you know how those plots are done? Which data are collected in order to obtain this, this have my curiousity :)

Comment: @Flugueubluck I would guess using Google Books data, but that's just a guess!

Comment: That's really interesting, thank you for sharing this, let me search a little bit in french now !

Comment: Est-ce que c'est ce genre de [graphique](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/11298/358) dont tu parles ? Clique sur l'image pour aller le voir sur le web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it on the Google Books page. Just change "Corpus" and you'll be able to choose the language that you want.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bonjour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbonjour%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Oh right, the Ngram Viewer! I totally forgot it gave the history. That's great, thanks!