# tout ce que / tout que

Tags: grammaire

> Le livre est tout ce que j’ai apporté.
>
> Le livre est tout que j’ai
> apporté.

I know the first one is correct. But is the other one also correct? If not, please tell me why.

> La lettre est tout ce que j’ai apporté.
>
> La lettre est toute ce que j’ai apportée.

I don’t know why should I use “toute” in the sentences.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>*Le livre est tout que j'ai apporté*</strike>  is not correct.

*Ce que* works as a lexical item where both words work together. *Ce* is a pronoun that represents the grammatical subject of the verb *est* and that appears just after the latter. It introduces the relative clause (*que j’ai apporté*) and is the direct object to the verb *ai apporté*.

**Tout** here is an adjective that qualifies *ce*. We could omit *tout* in the sentence (*le livre est ce que j'ai apporté*) and the sentence would still be correct - with a slight change in meaning of course. But the sentence cannot hold together without *ce*.

*Tout* in that case does not agree (therefore it would *la lettre est tout ce que j'ai apporté*, *les livres sont tout ce que j'ai apporté*). *Tout* qualifies *ce* which here is a neutral pronoun, it does not change, and *tout* does not change either.

---

<strike>Le livre est tout que j'ai apporté</strike>  n'est pas correct.

« **Ce que** » forme un ensemble inséparable dont les deux éléments sont indispensables. Le rôle de « ce »  est de reprendre le sujet (*le livre*) du verbe être après ce dernier, il introduit la proposition relative (*que j’ai apporté*) attribut du verbe *être*. Il sert d'antécédent à « que » qui est pronom relatif complément d'objet direct de *ai apporté*.

« **Tout** » ici est un adjectif qui qualifie « ce ». On pourrait supprimer « tout » sans problème (*le livre est ce que j'ai apporté*), mais pas « ce ».

« Tout » dans ce cas ne s'accorde pas (*la lettre est tout ce que j'ai apporté*). « Tout » qualifie « ce » qui est un pronom dit « neutre » et qui est ici invariable, et en conséquence « tout »  ne s'accorde pas non plus.

Comment: Thank you. Merci beaucoup. I now understand “tout” in the sentence is a noun. But “tout” can be a noun sometimes. I guess the noun “tout” can’t put “que” or “qui” right after it. Is my guess correct?

Comment: @Yamacure. Tout **here is an adjective**. But yes *tout* can sometimes be a pronoun, as in for example *j'ai tout vu*. *Ce que* and *ce que* are very specific, it is what we call "indefinite relative pronouns". See [that question here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11389/358) and the answer. [This](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/indefinite-relative-pronouns-ce-que-ce-qui/).

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. I know Tout is an adjective here.

Comment: I saw the question. But I still wonder if there’s a rule or a reason why “tout qui” and “tout que” are unacceptable.

Comment: @Yamacure It is unacceptable because we must have a noun or a pronoun in front of *qui/que*, *ce* is the pronoun that represents the noun. *Tout* is an adjective it can not serve as  a noun or pronoun. *ce que* as I said must stay together. In French we cannot omit the relative pronoun (here *ce que*) whereas in English it possible maybe that is why you find it difficult to understand? In English you can say "all that I brought with me" or "all I brought with me", in French the equivalent of "that" (*ce que*) cannot be omitted, it is just impossible.

Comment: Yes. That’s what confuses me. I know we must have a noun or a pronoun in front of qui/que. But “tout” also can be a noun or a pronoun in other cases. Then I want to know when “tout” can’t be a noun. Is it only before qui/que or are there more cases?

Comment: @Yamacure Ok, we then have identified the problem. I'll think about how to phrase something about that, and get back to you. But first it would help if you told me if you understand the notions of adjectives pronouns and adverbs, they might not exist in your mother tongue.

Comment: OK. Adjectives are words that describe nouns for example haut, bon. Pronouns are nouns that can mean other things according to the situation. “Tout” can be a pronoun, right? And adverbs describe adjectives and verbs and tell us how. This is my notion.

Comment: @Yamacure Do any of the following help? [French Word 'Tout' and Its Variations](https://www.thoughtco.com/french-word-tout-and-its-variations-1368964), [Tout](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/pdf/det9.pdf), [The Definitive Guide About the Word “tout”](http://frenchyourway.com.au/the-definitive-guide-about-the-word-tous-french-grammar-french-pronunciation).

Comment: Thank you. But it seems that there isn’t the answer. I really appreciate your replying to my comments so many times.